# Is there a way to create a loop logic that can select different option for each dropdown list and repeat it again for the next option?

Tags: r, python-3.x, algorithm, selenium, web-scraping

does anyone know how to automate web scraping on a dynamic web page using Selenium in Python or R?

**Situation:**
This page has a few dropdown category lists, and each category list has several options, e.g. Brand is one of a dropdown category list, and it has a lot of options to select such as ALFA ROMEO, AUDI, and so on. The same goes for other category lists as well. Furthermore, to select the option for the next category list, the previous or the option of the first category must be selected first. Once the option for all category lists has been selected, then the next phase is to click the "Get Valuation" button. It will output the information on the given table.

**Objective:**
The objective is to get all information from the table for all categories with all options and store it in .csv format.


**Screenshot 1 (list of options in a category):**
[image]


**Screenshot 2 (output):**
[image]

**Problem:**
I try to create a logic where it could click for each category and select one option at one time and then proceed to select the option on the next category. At the end of the process, it will click a submit button to get valuation information. But, my scripts only can click it for one option if the input were given. Then if I want to select the next option for all categories I have to use the same script over and over again with different input for index number(this refers to the element by id). This will be a tedious non-automatic job and can be a problem too if there is a newly updated list.


**Code sample to replicate:**

```
import time
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver .support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://www.carbase.my/tool/car-market-value-guide"
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\Noobie\Documents\utils\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
time.sleep(2)
driver.get(url)

def multi_define(driver, element_id, indexs):
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id(element_id))
    for index in indexs:
        select.select_by_index(index)

elem_cat = ('brand','family','year','cc','transmission','variant')

multi_define(driver, elem_cat[0], '2')
multi_define(driver, elem_cat[1], '2')
multi_define(driver, elem_cat[2], '2')
multi_define(driver, elem_cat[3], '2')
multi_define(driver, elem_cat[4], '1')
multi_define(driver, elem_cat[5], '1')
driver.find_element_by_id("loan-calculate").click()
```

Output:
**Refer to screenshot 2**


Could you guys advise on how to create a script that can loop and select a different option for each dropdown list and repeat it again for the next option?

Comment: You can do this with the rvest packages html_nodes(...) function. Each item in the dropdown will have an html "id" attribute, which points to the data associated with that dropdown item. I would use the html_nodes(...) function to make a list of ids, then use those ids to get the rest of the data. It looks like you are close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each select element, make the function select options one by one, then call itself recursively on the next select element.

While doing this, you can save the currently selected items in an array, and when you reach the last select item, use them however you want. Here is your code modified, that works on the URL you posted.

```py
driver.get(url)

elem_cat = ('brand','family','year','cc','transmission','variant')

def multi_define(driver, elem_index, selected):
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id(elem_cat[elem_index]))
    options = select.options

    # select each option
    for i in range(1, len(options)):
        select.select_by_index(i)
        time.sleep(0.3)

        if elem_index == 5:
            # we are at the last select item
            driver.find_element_by_id("loan-calculate").click()
            selected = selected + [options[i].text]
            
            # clicked the button. selected options are in selected array.
            # do whatever you need to do with this information
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print(selected)

        elif options[i].text != "": # skip placeholders
            # recursive call for the next select. you can change [options[i].text]
            # to whatever information you need about this option
            multi_define(driver, elem_index + 1, selected + [options[i].text])

multi_define(driver, 0, [])
```

Output of this code:

```
['ALFA ROMEO', '145', '2001', '1598', '5 SP MANUAL']
['ALFA ROMEO', '145', '2000', '1598', '5 SP MANUAL']
['ALFA ROMEO', '145', '1999', '1598', '5 SP MANUAL']
['ALFA ROMEO', '145', '1998', '1598', '5 SP MANUAL']
['ALFA ROMEO', '145', '1997', '1598', '5 SP MANUAL']
['ALFA ROMEO', '145', '1996', '1598', '5 SP MANUAL']
['ALFA ROMEO', '145', '1995', '1598', '5 SP MANUAL']
['ALFA ROMEO', '145', '1995', '1598', '5 SP MANUAL']
['ALFA ROMEO', '146', '2002', '1598', '5 SP MANUAL']
...
```

Comment: This is the logic that I'm looking for. It works wonderfully. Thank you very much my fren.

Comment: By the way, what is "multi_define(driver, 0, [])" means? The last line of code.

Comment: Although running a single script isn't efficient enough. I actually have an abstract idea of splitting the tasks by generating and triggering other scripts by counting the total of the options in the first dropdown list and then output it into a text file. The first script is the trigger script that will generate a text file and other scripts as well.

Comment: Its calculation is based on the formula "n1/n2=n3", where n1 is the total number of options, and n2 is the total script that will be used. A special condition will be added where if n3 == "floating point", then n2++. E.g. if there is 63 line of options then 63/2=31.5, but the condition is not satisfied therefore n2 will +1 become 63/3=21. So the first script will generate a text file with the total number of options for the first dropdown list and 3 scripts that will run the main logic. But there will be a problem on how to identify which scripts start on which options.

Comment: Second argument to `multi_define` is the index of select we are currently at. Initially we start with 0. The function selects an option in select 0, and calls itself with index 1. Then it will loop the options in select 1 (see `elem_index + 1` in `elif` block). Last argument is the array of currently selected options. Initially, we don't have anything selected. Thus `multi_define(driver, 0, [])`. At each selection, the function appends the current option to the array while calling itself: `selected + [options[i].text]`. I added a line to append the last option too, looks like I forgot that.

Comment: @Amz multiple scripts running in parallel sounds good. Maybe you should find a way  other than incrementing n2 until the division is a whole number. Because if you do that, you will need to have n2 = n1 scripts when n1 is a prime number.

Comment: *there will be a problem on how to identify which scripts start on which options* - right. Maybe your scripts need to take as an argument, which index to start with and which index to stop at.